# Creating angular base service and sub services

Tags: angularjs, prototypal-inheritance, angular-services

I'm trying to create a general service for dynamic listing objects i angular and for different types of Objects I need slightly different methods for this service. So I thought it would be the best to have a base service and some sub-services. The problem is, that I need to initialize the base service with different Objects depending on sub-service.

So that what I got so far:

Base List-Service (shortened to the relevant)

```
App.factory('List', ['$q',
    function (){

            var List = function(Item, searchParams){
                this.Item = Item;
                this.searchParams = searchParams;
                //....    
                this.nextPage();

            };
            //.....
            List.prototype.nextPage = function () {
                //.....
                this.Item.find({
                    //.....
                }.bind(this));
            };
            return List;
}]);
```

Sub-service of List-Service

```
App.factory('UserList', [
        'User', 'List','$q',
        function (User, List) {


            UserList = function(){

                var searchParams = {
                    // params Object
                };
                return new List(User, searchParams);
            };
            // extend base class:
            UserList.prototype.updateUser = function(id){
                  //.....
            }
            //....
            return UserList;
}]);
```

Currently just the UserList is loaded, but: Of course it loads every time a new instance, due the `new` operator when it's called, but I just want one instance. But leaving the `new` operator throw's an error that `this.nextPage();` would be undefined function. Beside this it seems the extension function `updateUser` is not applied.

So what's the best practice to inherit from other service with passing arguments to parent service in angular?

Answer (score 1):

I gotta work it.

changed sub service to this to inherit proper from base:

```
App.factory('UserList', [
    'User', 'List','$q',
    function (User, List) {

        var UserList = function(){
            var searchParams = {
                //.....
            };
            List.call(this, User, searchParams);
        };

        // inherit from List service
        UserList.prototype = Object.create(List.prototype);
        UserList.prototype.updateUser = function(id) {
            //.....
        };

        return UserList;
    }
])
```

;

Comment: useful resource http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/12/18/inheritance-services-controllers-in-angularjs/